# Limitations to the RETURN block in a MySQL function

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, sql-function, sql-limit

I'm working on a LeetCode [problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/nth-highest-salary/) that asks the user to return the Nth highest salary from a table called `Employee` with columns `Id` and `Salary`.

The code that the user is given to start with is

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNthHighestSalary(N INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
  RETURN (
      # Write your MySQL query statement below.
      
  );
END
```

The temptation is to put something like

```
  SELECT e.salary as getNthHighestSalary
  FROM employee e
  ORDER BY e.salary DESC
  LIMIT 1 OFFSET (N-1)
```

But evidently that doesn't work. Successful queries define another variable M=N-1 outside the return block, and then use `OFFSET M`.

My question:

> What is the principle involved here? Clearly there are some
> limitations as to what operations you're allowed to do inside the return block.

A reference is totally fine; some searching didn't yield anything.

Comment: Yeah, this is as interesting question, since you have a query that returns a single record with a single column - so the resultset is effectively a single value. I would guess (hence this is a comnent) that mysql treats select results as resultset even if the result is a single value. What makes it even more interesting that in case of SET statements, you can use a select statemsnt within () to return a single value and assign that to a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: you cannot use `offset (N-1)` there, because the syntax doesn't allow it. (And you should get a syntax error).

In general, [`limit` and `offset`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) expect the actual number:

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, **which must both be nonnegative integer constants**.

There is an exceptions though inside stored procedures:

> Within stored programs, LIMIT parameters can be specified using integer-valued routine parameters or local variables.

So you can use a variable there, but not an expression. That is why it works if you use  the precalculated variable `M` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION getNthHighestSalary2(N INT) RETURNS INT
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  RETURN
   (SELECT salary 
  FROM employee
  ORDER BY salary DESC
  LIMIT 1 OFFSET N);
  
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

The function return an integer, because you select only 1 value with LIMIT 1.

A result set with two rows, would produce an error.

the DETERMINISTIC i added because mysql wants there an option

Also tables can't be used as return value.

If you want to return more variables, you have to add user define variables after N INT, which can the be used in the SEELCT where you call the function